# Draw equal circle with in current location radius using Google Map SDK ios

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to divide current location radius (1000 meters) area into equal parts(100 meter each part) and get those center point coordinates in google map SDK. I am using google map sdk in my app. can any one help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeCir, longitudeCir)
                                                     radius:radiusValue];

            UIColor *colr = [UIColor colorWithRed:284.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:84.0/255.0 alpha:0.3];
              circ.fillColor = colr;
            circ.strokeColor =  colr;

            circ.map = _mapkitView;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var num = 0
        //First we declare While to repeat adding Annotation
        while num != 15 {
            num += 1

            let rotateDegree : CLLocationDegrees = 90
            //Add Annotation
            let annotation = GMSMarker()
            annotation.position = generateRandomCoordinates(min: 1000, max: 10000) //this will be the maximum and minimum distance of the annotation from the current Location (Meters)
            annotation.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            annotation.rotation = rotateDegree
            annotation.icon = UIImage.init(named: "icon_machine_location")
            annotation.map = mapView
        }
```

**Generate Random Coordinates Function**

```
func generateRandomCoordinates(min: UInt32, max: UInt32)-> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        //Get the Current Location's longitude and latitude
        let currentLong = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
        let currentLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude

        //1 KiloMeter = 0.00900900900901° So, 1 Meter = 0.00900900900901 / 1000
        let meterCord = 0.00900900900901 / 1000

        //Generate random Meters between the maximum and minimum Meters
        let randomMeters = UInt(arc4random_uniform(max) + min)

        //then Generating Random numbers for different Methods
        let randomPM = arc4random_uniform(6)

        //Then we convert the distance in meters to coordinates by Multiplying number of meters with 1 Meter Coordinate
        let metersCordN = meterCord * Double(randomMeters)

        //here we generate the last Coordinates
        if randomPM == 0 {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat + metersCordN, longitude: currentLong + metersCordN)
        }else if randomPM == 1 {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat - metersCordN, longitude: currentLong - metersCordN)
        }else if randomPM == 2 {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat + metersCordN, longitude: currentLong - metersCordN)
        }else if randomPM == 3 {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat - metersCordN, longitude: currentLong + metersCordN)
        }else if randomPM == 4 {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat, longitude: currentLong - metersCordN)
        }else {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat - metersCordN, longitude: currentLong)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply...But  It's not covering all the area with in 1000 meters. I need to cover every area to my surroundings upto 1000 meters. Each area part should be 100 meters. It's randomly generating few areas.